# How to generate serial number 1,2,3,etc.. using datatable angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am create small demo for listing user list using datatable angularjs.user list working very well in demo. now I want to generate serial number 1 to n..in table 1 to 100 records is store then want to serial number 1 to 100.

here I am done with this code:

```
app.controller("userscontroller", ["$scope", "$http", "DTOptionsBuilder", "DTColumnBuilder", "userservice","$compile"
function ($scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, userservic,$compile) {       

    $scope.dtColumns = [            
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("fullName", "Full Name").withOption('name', 'firstname'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("username", "Name").withOption('name', 'username'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("email", "Email").withOption('name', 'email'), 
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Action').withOption('defaultContent', ' ').notSortable()
            .renderWith(function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if (data.UserCount > 1)
                    return '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="delete(' + data.id + ');"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>' + '</button>';                    
            })          
    ]

    $scope.dtOptions = userservice.GetAllUser(DTOptionsBuilder)
    .withOption('processing', true)
    .withOption('serverSide', true)
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
    .withDisplayLength(50)
    .withOption('aaSorting', [3, 'desc'])

     function createdRow(row, data, dataIndex) {
        $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
    }
}]);
```

here is my html code:

```
<table id="tbluserlist" datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" dt-instance="dtInstance" class="table table-hover"> </table>
```

How to do that task?

Comment: serial number means just for showing purpose only ah?

Comment: yes just showing purpose but i need and want

Comment: just use $index inside ng-repeat.. Ex. <td>{{$index+1}}</td>

Comment: but i am not used ng-repeat i m used datatable for the show listing wit i am add my html code also. i  edited my question

Answer (score 1):

finally i got answer just write this code.

```
.withOption('fnRowCallback',function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){
        $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex +1);
        return nRow;
    })
```

and add your column in table :

```
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('No.').withOption('defaultContent', ' ').notSortable(),
```

this is first column.